# How can I animate infinite marker movement down an SVG path without very high CPU usage?

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

I wish to implement flow indicators on the links of my D3 graph, as in [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/nitaku/1adb4033d7078f7d005e).

The block uses stroke-dashoffset keyframe CSS animation to achieve the flow, and while it looks good, CPU usage sits at almost 100.

I read that you can trick some browsers into triggering GPU acceleration by including certain CSS properties, but other sources indicated that this no longer works, and certainly I couldn't see any benefit when trying to add `transform: translateZ(0);` (for example).

I have been investigating other options, and I tried to implement a moving marker along a line, in [this](http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/8163022) style. For only one marker performance is better, but when I added multiple performance was worse.

Is there another, more performant option for animating a marker down an SVG path?

Failing another approach, I will try adding controls to stop / start the animation, but that would be a last resort.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems indeed that animating the `stroke-dashoffset` attribute causes a lot of calculations. The original example causes a CPU usage at around 50% when I open it in Firefox.

There's another approach that seems to give better results: manually increment the `stroke-dashoffset` and loop that using `setInterval`.  Here's a proof of concept:

http://bl.ocks.org/kmandov/raw/a87de2dd49a21be9f95c/

Here's how I update the dashoffset:

```
var lines = d3.selectAll('.flowline');

var offset = 1; 
setInterval(function() {
  lines.style('stroke-dashoffset', offset);
  offset += 1; 
}, 50);
```

I know that it doesn't look very good but it (surprisingly) performs a lot better than relying on css animations or transitions. In Firefox I now get CPU usage at about 15%.

I can imagine that this approach won't perform very well if you have a lot of links, because the update will take too long. But maybe it's a viable hack for simpler use cases where you animate linearly a fixed amount of links.

Comment: It's a huge improvement! I think I could adapt this for use. Thanks :)