# SVG animations: sluggish/poor performance in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, performance, animation, svg

We're developing a fairly complex scene with a lot of moving parts, which up until now didn't involve any SVG animation.

Everything has been smooth and performing well, until we introduced an SVG with a few dashed lines that we animated using the stroke-dashoffset property.

It makes absolutely no difference in Edge or Firefox, but in Chrome the animation of the entire scene becomes choppy and sluggish.

We've even tried both means to the same end - CSS keyframes and SMIL inside the SVG element - but both perform equally poorly.

Is there a performance trick for Chrome that we're missing?

Edit: Example

Markup:

```css
.stream {
  animation: stream 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes stream {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.0" id="streams" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 225.32 66.19" enable-background="new 0 0 225.32 66.19" xml:space="preserve">
      <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="3,4" d="M107.38,50.54c0,0-6.78-84.52-106.51-22.2" />
      <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="3,4" d="M110.49,45.31c-0.63-13.01-4.56-44.87-27.83-43.8c-27.6,1.27-37.33,39.66-38.49,60.34"/>
      <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="3,4" d="M180.63,59.88c-0.69-9.65-3.6-30.18-15.76-45.51C148.44-6.34,131.85,2.22,128.87,5c-2.89,2.7-12.81,7.14-14.28,42"/>
      <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="3,4" d="M118.59,45.41c2.4-10.18,9.9-31.97,30.87-37.59c26.03-6.98,55.13,9.32,72.02,19.37"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: are you using requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: Got an example to reproduce?

Comment: We're using requestAnimationFrame for any JS animations, yeah. The SVG animations use SMIL or CSS (both of which were sluggish) so it doesn't apply there.

Comment: anyway you can refactor your css to js animations so you can make benefits of performance optimizations, not alot you can do with css, and especially when you're not showing examples.

Comment: are you using transition or transform mostly?

Comment: I'll add an example to the post.

Comment: For me, it's smooth on both Chrome 69/Windows and Chromium 70/Debian, provided I wait for the initial loading processes having run their course. Does the problem continue after the page has been fully loaded? Do you have tested it with different profiles to make sure the issue isn't with some browser extension?

Answer (score 3):

duplicate of [How can I animate infinite marker movement down an SVG path without very high CPU usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749245/how-can-i-animate-infinite-marker-movement-down-an-svg-path-without-very-high-cp)

the real problem here are poor svg-implementations, see [chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167569)

one workaround does reduce the frame-rate with a javascript animation, see the code sample

this particular case can be done with a dashed circle and css `transform: rotate3d()`. but also the "GPU transforms" translate/rotate have poor performance in today's svg implementations. workaround: wrap svg code inside a `<div>` and animate the div, and voila! cpu goes down to zero. related: [crmarsh.com/svg-performance](https://www.crmarsh.com/svg-performance/)

```js
const svg_elem = document.getElementById('streams')

const animateDashTime = 200 // milliseconds
let anim_dash_offset = 0
let animateDashTimer = null

function animateDashStep(){

  anim_dash_offset += 1

  svg_elem.setAttribute('style',
    '--stroke-dashoffset: '+anim_dash_offset);

  // repeat
  animateDashTimer = setTimeout(
    animateDashStep,
    animateDashTime
  )
}

// start
animateDashStep()

// stop
//clearTimeout(animateDashTimer)
```

```html
<svg version="1.0" id="streams" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 225.32 66.19" enable-background="new 0 0 225.32 66.19" xml:space="preserve" 

  style="--stroke-dashoffset: 0"
>
  <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" 
  
    stroke-dasharray="3,4" 
    stroke-dashoffset="var(--stroke-dashoffset)" 

    d="M107.38,50.54c0,0-6.78-84.52-106.51-22.2"
  />
  <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="3,4" stroke-dashoffset="var(--stroke-dashoffset)" d="M110.49,45.31c-0.63-13.01-4.56-44.87-27.83-43.8c-27.6,1.27-37.33,39.66-38.49,60.34"
  />
  <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="3,4" stroke-dashoffset="var(--stroke-dashoffset)" d="M180.63,59.88c-0.69-9.65-3.6-30.18-15.76-45.51C148.44-6.34,131.85,2.22,128.87,5c-2.89,2.7-12.81,7.14-14.28,42"/>
  <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="3,4" stroke-dashoffset="var(--stroke-dashoffset)" d="M118.59,45.41c2.4-10.18,9.9-31.97,30.87-37.59c26.03-6.98,55.13,9.32,72.02,19.37"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the **ease** on your animation to `linear`. Run the snippet below to see it run without that chunky slow-down.

```css
.stream {
  animation: stream 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes stream {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.0" id="streams" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 225.32 66.19" enable-background="new 0 0 225.32 66.19" xml:space="preserve">
      <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="3,4" d="M107.38,50.54c0,0-6.78-84.52-106.51-22.2" />
      <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="3,4" d="M110.49,45.31c-0.63-13.01-4.56-44.87-27.83-43.8c-27.6,1.27-37.33,39.66-38.49,60.34"/>
      <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="3,4" d="M180.63,59.88c-0.69-9.65-3.6-30.18-15.76-45.51C148.44-6.34,131.85,2.22,128.87,5c-2.89,2.7-12.81,7.14-14.28,42"/>
      <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="3,4" d="M118.59,45.41c2.4-10.18,9.9-31.97,30.87-37.59c26.03-6.98,55.13,9.32,72.02,19.37"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: That didn't solve the issue of the sluggishness (another change I made did, although I'm not sure what!) but it DID make the animation much better, so thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Geat Did you ever figure out what change fixed the lag, and do you remember what it was? I'm having the same issue with animating stroke-dashoffset...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [the JavaScript approach given by Mila Nautikus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60167976/2369823), you can simply use `animation-timing-function: steps(n)` to achieve to the same effect. Setting `n` to `m * (how many stroke-dashoffset changed during an animation loop)` for a smoother animation, for example:

```css
.stream {
  animation: stream 0.5s steps(14) infinite;
}

@keyframes stream {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 7;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.0" id="streams" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 225.32 66.19" enable-background="new 0 0 225.32 66.19" xml:space="preserve">
      <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="3,4" d="M107.38,50.54c0,0-6.78-84.52-106.51-22.2" />
      <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="3,4" d="M110.49,45.31c-0.63-13.01-4.56-44.87-27.83-43.8c-27.6,1.27-37.33,39.66-38.49,60.34"/>
      <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="3,4" d="M180.63,59.88c-0.69-9.65-3.6-30.18-15.76-45.51C148.44-6.34,131.85,2.22,128.87,5c-2.89,2.7-12.81,7.14-14.28,42"/>
      <path class="stream" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.75" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="3,4" d="M118.59,45.41c2.4-10.18,9.9-31.97,30.87-37.59c26.03-6.98,55.13,9.32,72.02,19.37"/>
</svg>
```